# Change file and image dynamically in JWPlayer 5 with Javascript API

Tags: jwplayer

There's an HTML playlist and I want to change the current video and image when user clicks on an item in the playlist but it's not working. What's wrong with my code?

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="item-video">
    <script>
        var playerData = {
            file: 'dummy-file.flv',
            image: 'dummy-image.jpg',
            autostart: false
        }
    </script>
    <div id="item-player"></div>
    <div class="playlist">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="thumb-holder" href="#" data-video="new-video.flv" data-image="new-image.jpg" title="test">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <span>test</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
if ($(".item-video").length) {
    if (typeof playerData != 'undefined') {
        jwplayer('item-player').setup({
            file: playerData.file,
            image: playerData.image,
            height: '300',
            width: '420',
            stretching: 'uniform',
            smoothing: 'false',
            modes: [
                { 'type': 'html5' },
                { 'type': 'flash', src: '/mediaplayer/player.swf' },
                { 'type': 'download' }
            ],
            autostart: playerData.autostart,
            backcolor: '#efefef',
            controlbar: 'bottom',
            skin: '/mediaplayer/skins/bekle/bekle.zip',
            allowscriptaccess: 'always',

        });
    }
    $(".playlist").delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
        var $item = $(this);
        var video = $item.attr('data-video');
        var image = $item.attr('data-image');
        if (typeof video != 'undefined') {
            jwplayer().load({
                file: video,
                image: (typeof image != 'undefined') ? image : ""

            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

*It seems that JWPlayer guys have removed documentation of JWPlayer 5 and they suggest to upgrade to JWPlayer 6 but I can't!*

Comment: Do you have a link to where this code is running? Also, the JW5 documentation was just moved, it was not removed. It now resides here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/

Comment: Unfortunately code is running on my local until I can find a solution for this problem. I'm sure I don't have any other javascript errors on my page if you are asking for my page for this.

Comment: Could it be because of my JWPlayer version? It's 5.2. Does this API works on all JWPlayer 5 versions?

Comment: You need at least 5.3+ for our API to work properly.

Comment: Contrary to the response from 'emaxsaun', JW5 docs have been completely removed. I'm one of those people with JW5, and no intention to give them more money for an upgrade I don't need. It's a shame they don't respect licensed owners of JW5, and make available JW5 docs. Kind of shows what sort of company they are.

Comment: @RedRum Try compiling the JW source code that is available on GitHub. I've done it; It works and you won't need another license.

Comment: @Farid That's okay, I was only commenting on the removal of documentation for JW5, their attempt at erasing their own history to increase sales. I spent US$97 on JW5, but never used it that much. I have since found fragments of the JS API docs via archive.org, enough to solve my problem, but it's rotten I had to resort to that. I have only basic video player needs, including offline use, which I understand is not possible with JW after version 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Ethan LongTail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645000/ethan-longtail) suggestion, the problem was because of using an earlier version of JWPlayer (I was using 5.2 and API works with 5.3+).

Updating the player fixed the problem.